# OrgChartJS Node alignment in Grouping

Tags: orgchart

Is it possible to align the nodes inside a grouping beneath each other?

The BalkanGraph/OrgChart JS [Demo](https://balkangraph.com/OrgChartJS/Demos/Grouping) shows the nodes next to each other as well as stacked/beneath each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BALKANGraph developer evangelist here

The current version does nor support requested functionality

As workaround you can use mixed layout